# IntelliJ IDEA Project with Angular and Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

i've created an IntelliJ 'Empty Project' and added 2 Modules: One for Spring Boot (Backend) and one for Angular CLI (Frontend). So far, so good.
[File Structure of my Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbQPM.png)

Now i added the project to GitLab and got problems when cloning the project, bc for some reason it sometimes only gets one module.
Also I got Problems with .gitignore file, bc this would need to be outside of a specific module in my root-project. The same for .gitlab-ci.yml.

I can't add anything into my project except for new modules. Or at least it is then only shown in the project structure like here:[Hidden folders in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZC2O.png)

What i now would need is some kind of root module/project which has the Spring and ANgular Modules as childs. So that they can start separately. But still can have some project-level files.

Is there any way to achieve this in IntelliJ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Either manage them as separate git projects and then make sure you have configured git root for each in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | **Version Control** or have them bot under same parent directory and manage it as a single git project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it well, what you want is similar to a mono-repo ? I don't know if thee is any libs that can help you doing that in java. But you can give a try to git submodules (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). It works with Gitlab.

You just have to create a `.gitmodules` file in root folder and reference your both git project. then you have plenty of command that can help you (like get your whole project with only one git clone).

resource : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule

hope it'll help !

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out.   Yes, i want a single-repo with 2 modules in it, but i can't put anything in the root directory, which also contains the two modules...   I've read about doing a Gradle/Maven Project as root instead of intellij's empty project, could that help?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of Gradle/Maven to answer this one :|

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to just create two separate projects, with different repos in GitLab. And then, you could open them separately in IntelliJ. From the workflow perspective, this approach would be more natural. For example, when you do work on the frontend, you keep your backend running, but do changes only in the frontend and vice-versa.

Comment: But in IntelliJ i can also run two or more applications at the same time. So why should I use two IntelliJ instances, when one can handle them?